# Change TextInputLayout hint color with error message color

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

[image: screenshot containing two input fields with red hint text]

I want to change the hint color to white and keep the color for the error messages red. I have tried all of the possible options but each time the hint color was changed to the color of the error message.

This is the code snippet I used for the style of error messages:

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/error_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I solve it by setting the backgroundTintList (the underline, officially called Activation indicator) to red and make a TextView holding the error message. Which means I totally give up using the input Layout.error method

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://medium.com/omisoft/textinputlayout-styling-8b36a5e0d73c) explains how to style TextInputLayout in the way that you need.

**TLDR**

> Hint color could be set via `android:textColorHint` parameter of
> `TextInputLayout`. This parameter also changes the label default color
> (label focused color could also be changed in other ways)
>
> Such parameters as `app:hintTextAppearance`,
> `app:helperTextTextAppearance` and `app:errorTextAppearance` together
> with all the necessary text parameters of styles.xml should be used to
> customize labels, helpers and errors in `TextInputLayout`. The parent of
> the text appearance style should be `TextAppearance.AppCompat` or some
> of its children.
>
> Also, please keep in mind the following: `app:hintTextAppearance`
> affects the focused label color and label size in any state; when an
> error is shown, the bottom/border line will have the color indicated
> in the `android:textColor` parameter of `errorTextAppearance`. This
> color will be changed to the default once the error is removed.